# Powershell equivalent of Bash Brace Expansion for generating lists/arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, brace-expansion

When writing a Bash script you can use [brace expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) to quickly generate lists:

[image: Bash Brace Expansion]

What is the simplest way to generate a similar list in Powershell? I can use the .. or , operators to [generate an array](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/12/09/easily-create-and-manipulate-an-array-of-arrays-in-powershell.aspx), but how can I prefix the items with a static string literal?

```
PS C:\Users\gb> 1..5
1
2
3
4
5

PS C:\Users\gb> "test"+1..5
test1 2 3 4 5

PS C:\Users\gb> "test","dev","prod"
test
dev
prod

PS C:\Users\gb> "asdf"+"test","dev","prod"
asdftest dev prod
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
PS C:\> "test","dev","prod" | % { "server-$_" }
server-test
server-dev
server-prod
PS C:\> 1..5 | % { "server{0:D2}" -f $_ }
server01
server02
server03
server04
server05
PS C:\> 1..5 | % { "192.168.0.$_" }
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
```

Note that `%` is an alias for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.

Comment: How would you do `rn file{,.old}`?

Comment: Like this? : `$cmdargs = $(('','.old') | % { "test.txt$($_)".ToString() }) ; Rename-Item @cmdargs`

Answer (score 10):

I'm hoping to be proven wrong here, but I don't believe there is a way to do it *exactly* like with bash, or with as few keystrokes.

You can iterate over the list by piping it through a `foreach-object` to achieve the same result though.

`1..5 | foreach-object { "test" + $_ }`

Or using the shorthand:

`1..5 | %{"test$_"}`

In both cases (`%` is an alias for `foreach-object`), the output is:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
```

Note: if you're building this into a script for publishing/distribution/reuse, use the more verbose `foreach-object`, not the shorthand `%` - for readability.

Comment: `1..5 | %{ "test$_" }` is even shorter still.

Comment: Correct you are - edited my code. I really need to break that concatenation habit.

Comment: Yeah I thought about just using for each, but it was a bit too verbose. `1..5 | %{"server{0:00}" -f $_}` is short enough that I'll probably just use that unless someone can think of a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: `foreach ($x in $y) {stuff}` does get verbose, but for some things it's the way to go (and would be valid here). In this case, `foreach-object` with the pipeline is much less verbose.

Answer (score 3):

I have a way to do it using [int's tostring method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring?view=netcore-3.1).  The '000' at the end is a special format code.  It always pads to the right number of zeros.  You can also use wildcards with method names like t*g if you really want to be terse and mysterious.

```
1..10 | % tostring computer000

computer001
computer002
computer003
computer004
computer005
computer006
computer007
computer008
computer009
computer010


1..10 | % t*g 192\.168\.1\.0

192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7
192.168.1.8
192.168.1.9
192.168.1.10
```

'x' is also a format code for hex printing.

```
10..15 | % tostring x

a
b
c
d
e
f
```

There's always -replace, which also works on arrays.  '^' is regex for 'beginning of line'.  Use '$' instead for 'end of line'.

```
(echo test dev prod) -replace '^','server-'

server-test
server-dev
server-prod
```

Hah, I never tried this before.

```
(echo test dev prod) -replace (echo ^ server-)

server-test
server-dev
server-prod
```

Maybe they could do that brace expansion in powershell 8...

Answer (score 1):

**Major Edit:** Updated to support multiple expansions in a single string. Should be a little safer not using `Invoke-Expression` for the number range.

I don't know how "Production-Ready" this is but it emulates the original syntax as much as possible.

This adds a special `expand()` method to the core string type which means I have committed a grave sin. If you want the function version please skip to the bottom.

Unfortunately, native Powershell cmdlets do not allow splatting unless the value is assigned to a variable first. So you can't do `"do-thing "{foo,bar}".expand()` but you could do `"$foobar = "{foo,bar}".expand(); do-thing @foobar"`.

However, it does pair well with destructuring `"$foo, $bar = "{foo,bar}".expand()"` and pipelines `"{foo,bar,baz}.txt".expand() | New-Item -Name { $_ }`. That pipeline uses delayed binding to assigned the piped values to the correct parameter since the cmdlet can't do so itself.

```
$ExpandMethod = [scriptblock] {
    
    $Expandables = [Regex]::Matches($this, "{([^}]+)}")  # Match everything between curlies that isn't a right curly
    $Strings = @($this)  # Seed initial value for foreach loop

    foreach ($Expandable in $Expandables) {

        # Return array based on whether we're working with strings
        # or numbers.
        $Transforms = switch ($Expandable.Groups[1].Value) {
            { $_.Contains(',')  } { $_.Split(',') }
            { $_.Contains('..') } { [int]$Start, [int]$End = $_ -split '\.\.'; $Start..$End }
            default { throw [System.InvalidOperationException] "Could not determine how to expand string." }
        }

        $TempStrings = @()
        foreach ($Transform in $Transforms) {
            foreach ($String in $Strings) {
                $TempStrings += $String -Replace $Expandable.Value, $Transform
            }
        }

        # Overwrite to ensure that expandables in the next run only used
        # transformed strings.
        $Strings = $TempStrings
    }

    return $Strings
}

Update-TypeData -TypeName 'System.String' `
    -MemberType 'ScriptMethod' `
    -MemberName 'Expand' `
    -Value $ExpandMethod `
    -Force

"/{foo,bar}/{bim,bam}/test{1..3}.txt".expand()

# Result
#> /foo/bim/test1.txt
#> /bar/bim/test1.txt
#> /foo/bam/test1.txt
#> /bar/bam/test1.txt
#> /foo/bim/test2.txt
#> /bar/bim/test2.txt
#> /foo/bam/test2.txt
#> /bar/bam/test2.txt
#> /foo/bim/test3.txt
#> /bar/bim/test3.txt
#> /foo/bam/test3.txt
#> /bar/bam/test3.txt
```

Oh, did you think we were done? Perish the thought dear reader, I shall not go quietly into the night but screaming with this final blasphemous act.

Behold as we use the function version of `expand()` to take our command as a script block, expand the provided string, insert it into the script block and since it is a variable, it can now be splatted against our command, circumventing the restrictions mentioned above.

```
function Expand-StringBrace {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias('expand')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $Command,
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $String,

        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments,DontShow)]
        [String] $UnboundArgs
    )
    
    $Expandables = [Regex]::Matches($String, "{([^}]+)}")  # Match everything between curlies that isn't a right curly
    $Strings = @($String)  # Seed initial value for foreach loop

    foreach ($Expandable in $Expandables) {

        # Return array based on whether we're working with strings
        # or numbers.
        $Transforms = switch ($Expandable.Groups[1].Value) {
            { $_.Contains(',')  } { $_.Split(',') }
            { $_.Contains('..') } { [int]$Start, [int]$End = $_ -split '\.\.'; $Start..$End }
            default { throw [System.InvalidOperationException] "Could not determine how to expand string." }
        }

        $TempStrings = @()
        foreach ($Transform in $Transforms) {
            foreach ($String in $Strings) {
                $TempStrings += $String -Replace $Expandable.Value, $Transform
            }
        }

        # Overwrite to ensure that expandables in the next run only used
        # transformed strings.
        $Strings = $TempStrings
    }

    # Create script that splats the given command with the parsed brace expansion
    # and passes the remaining args to the command.
    $ScriptBlock = [ScriptBlock]::Create("$Command @_ @UnboundArgs")

    $PSVars = @([psvariable]::new('_', $Strings), [psvariable]::new('UnboundArgs', $UnboundArgs))
    $ScriptBlock.InvokeWithContext($null, $PSVars)
}

new-item test.txt
expand Rename-Item "test{.txt,.log}" -Verbose
# or
#"test{.txt,.log}" | expand Rename-Item
```