# create multiple subdirectory using mkdir in powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, brace-expansion

Is there a way I can do this in ms powershell? (w/o scripting)

```
mkdir a\b\c\d{a,b,c,d}
```

I want to make multiple subdirectories at once just like in bash
but when i run it in powershell it gives me this error :

> At line:1 char:17
>   + mkdir a\b\c\d{a,b,c,d}
>   +                 ~
>   Missing argument in parameter list.
>   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:)  [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument**

I had tried all of the following:

```
mkdir a\b\c\d\{a b c d}
mkdir a\b\c\d\a,b,c,d}
mkdir a\b\c\d\[a,b,c,d]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"a","b","c","d" | % { mkdir "a\b\c\d\$_" }
```

or

```
echo a,b,c,d | % { mkdir "a\b\c\d\$_" }
```

See: [Powershell equivalent of Bash Brace Expansion for generating lists/arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16222477/3776858)

Comment: This definitely serves my purpose, now I understand why i'm doing it wrong.