# Powershell Equivalent of Bash Brace Expansion for a Single Command?

Tags: powershell

So, first off, I have seen: [Powershell equivalent of Bash Brace Expansion for generating lists/arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222477/powershell-equivalent-of-bash-brace-expansion-for-generating-lists-arrays), but that doesn't quite address what I want.

In that case, the author is fine with the expansion being multiple calls to the same command. However, one of my favorite "power user" features of Bash was the below:

```
mv test{1,2}.md
```

Which expands nicely into:

```
mv test1.md test2.md
```

This was amazing for renaming, copying, or removing related files and all sorts of other things. Does PowerShell have anything like that?

I tried a format string:

```
mv ("{0}1{1} {0}2{1}" -f "test",".md")
```

But, not only is that rather cumbersome, it passes the combined format string as one arg to `mv`.

So, does the shortcut I seek exist in PowerShell? My Google-fu has failed me.

Comment: `mv test[12].md foo -whatif`

Comment: `mv test[12].md foo -whatif` doesn't really do what I want. That will move both `test1.md` and `test2.md` to `foo`. That's useful for renaming two files at once, but not 100% the spirit of the question.

Comment: Sounds like `{a,b}` is some kind of syntactic sugar in bash. I don't know of an equivalent in PowerShell off the top of my head. It may be possible to write a function but there'd need to be a spec.